# Dynamically render multiple columns based on a drop-down list

Tags: tableau-api, dynamic-columns

I have a table in tableau with say 4 columns (Say Employee ID, Name, Address, Email).

I want to provide the users an option to select single/multiple columns from a drop down list (assume in the drop down list we have columns headers, Customfield1, Customfield2.....,Customfield10) which would be added to the table as a separate columns.

Say for Instance if the user selects CustomField1, CustomField2, CustomField3 from the drop-down list then the table should have in total of 7 columns (4 Emp fields + 3 Custom Fields)

Though I stated a simple requirement, my idea was to extrapolate that to something complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think some version of this could be done, albeit in a hacky way. What you're looking for is 'Dynamic Parameters.' They don't technically officially exist in the product, but can be created with the combination of parameter and calculated field.

[Here is a link to a method on such creation.](https://themarkscard.com/2016/08/03/who-says-tableau-parameters-arent-dynamic/)

The idea here would be to *re-order* columns in a custom manner. Each calculated field would have to have its own logic for which dimension it was to display when a user selected a parameter. (ie: With parameter selection A Column 1 goes to [Name] and Column 2 goes to [Address], and with parameter selection B Column 1 goes to [Address] and Column 2 goes to [Name].) The caveat here is that each potential layout would need to have the same number of columns - there is not a way to add columns dynamically. Consider that each column is represented here with a calculated field.

Good luck on it.

Comment: Any luck here? If so, please upvote and apply green check/tick mark. If you were able to solve on your own please place an answer to your own question. Thank you!